# Flutter - connect two devices using Bluetooth through an app without pairing first

Tags: android, bluetooth, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages, flutter-android

How can I connect two devices using Bluetooth through an app? Without having to connect the Bluetooth connection manually like we usually do. Let's say the app is running in the background and the Bluetooth connects automatically for the first time or multiple times and sends each other a message.

I want to do this without user intervention. The app running in the background will connect to a device running the same app. So the app can send a message, that the user has predefined.

It does not matter if it is not secure. Just need to do this for an assignment.

Comment: It’s not possible for an app to connect Bluetooth devices without the user’s permission.

Comment: Connecting without user intervention is possible using Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) as long as no security features are enabled (no pairing). But I'm not sure about using BLE in the background using flutter. Hope this helps you with your research